# Should i prefer using inline static member variables?

Tags: c++, inline, static-variables

i have a lot of classes with static member variables without inline, and now i am refactoring them. Are inline static member variables slower than their counterparts? (i read that inlined **METHODS** are bad for performance, is it same with **VARIABLES**)

**Which one i should prefer:**

**with inline:**

```
class AClass
{
public:
    //standart data types
    static inline int LastStaticIndex = 0;
    static inline bool Log_AllEnabled = false;

    //a struct (in microsoft case "CRITICAL_SECTION")
    static inline Mutex mutex;

    //a struct with member with dynamic size
    static inline std::string Text = "testing";
};
```

**without inline:**

```
class AClass
{
public:
    //standart data types
    static int LastStaticIndex;
    static bool Log_AllEnabled;

    //a struct (in microsoft case "CRITICAL_SECTION")
    static Mutex mutex;

    //a struct with member with dynamic size
    static std::string Text;
};

//cpp file, (or even same header file)
int AClass::LastStaticIndex = 0;
bool AClass::Log_AllEnabled = false;

Mutex AClass::mutex = Mutex();

std::string AClass::Text = "testing";
```

Comment: Yes, it's designed for such purposes.

Comment: does it have a performance issue? i read that inilned METHODS are bad for performance, is it same with VARIABLES

Comment: Where did you hear inline was bad for performance?  It's quite the opposite, in fact.  Since the full definition of an inline function or variable is visible from more places in the program the compiler likely has _more_ opportunity for optimizations.  The differences are likely very small (especially if you're using link time/whole program optimization), but they tend to fall more in the direction of _better_ performance with inline definitions, not worse.